# Removing partial duplicates from a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a csv file of ~1800 lines. The file contains multiple duplicates that I want to get rid of while keeping only one original line. E.g.:

1. We are joining the protest #protest #join http://someurl
2. We are joining the protest #victory
3. #letsrock We are joining the protest! http://anotherurl

I want to get rid of the last two lines while keeping the first one. I decided to use thefuzz to do this (which uses difflib). However, it deletes some relevant lines or removes some of the duplicates only. Here's my code:

```
from thefuzz import fuzz, process
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", dtype=str, lineterminator='\n')
threshold = 80
processed = []

for lines in df['Content']:
    scores = process.extract(lines, df['Content'], scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio)
    if scores[1][1] < threshold:
        processed.append(max([x[0] for x in scores[:2]], key=len))
    else:
        continue

dframe = pd.DataFrame(processed)
dframe.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Is there any other way to remove this kind of duplicates or something else I should consider/pay attention to?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could get rid of all the hashtags and urls and leave only the text, normalize it and try with unique()?

Comment: Actually it may solve the problem. Will try that!